# VIM highlight breaks on PHP regular expression

Tags: php, vim, syntax-highlighting

It breaks after scrolling up and down couple of times. I'm wondering if this is just happening to me or if anyone else has the same issue, and if there is anyway to fix it.

I have a string as:

```
preg_match_all("/<img.*?src=.([\/.a-z0-9@:_-]+).*?>/si", $str);
```

Comment: Syntax highlighting is heuristics in most editors. Noone implements a complete language parser for that. :}

Comment: I assume is cause of the *?> at the end of the regex.

Comment: What version of vim are you using?

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.1 (2007 May 12, compiled Oct 17 2008 18:11:28)
Included patches: 1-314

Comment: that's interesting, does it for me too on v7.2.330

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to me too in v7.2.330. Not sure you're going to be able to fix it unless you dig into the PHP parser.

Maybe consider filing a bug with VIM?

-tjw

Answer (score 0):

It's as if vim 7.4 has having problems with it's new regex engine. I've come to a quick fix searching for regex break under javascript. It basically tells vim to use the old regexengine (the fully tested one xD)

```
:set regexpengine=1
:syntax enable
```

Hope it helps, and here's the reference
https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript/issues/93